# Route::get()->uri() remembers current controller

Tags: php, kohana

If I click in my link, I'm redirected to /podstrony/podstrony/xyz.

I try to make a link with the method "Route::get()->uri()" in the following way:

```
    $url = Route::get('podstrony')->uri(array(
        'title' => 'xyz',
    ));
```

and I set it like below

```
    $view->body = __('Example text').'<a href="'.$url.'">click</a>';

    $this->response->body($view);
```

The routes in bootstrap.php look like

```
Route::set('podstrony', 'podstrony(/<title>)')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'podstrony',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'welcome',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

and the base url is set to "/" only (I have kohana in the root directory).

How to get rid of the repeated controller?

Answer (score 0):

I found some solution for the issue.
We can replace "Route::get(controller)->uri(params)" by "Route::url(controller, params)".
However I would like to know how to do a relative link url.